# Submitting a Spark Scala (.jar) job via .NET Azure HDInsight API

Tags: c#, scala, azure, azure-hdinsight

I've been trying to submit a job to my spark cluster via the azure hdinsight api in .NET. I have already checked that my scala code works by submitting it via the Intellij Azure Plugin -> Submit Spark Application to HDInsight but I can't make it work when submitting the job via the .net api. (Possibly the job submission type is incorrect?) I get a jobId and a jobComplete status but it does not write the outputs properly.

Scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object HDInsightScala{

def main (arg: Array[String]): Unit = {
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HDInsightScala")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val rdd = sc.textFile("wasbs:///HdiSamples/HdiSamples/SensorSampleData/hvac/HVAC.csv")

//find the rows which have only one digit in the 7th column in the CSV
val rdd1 =  rdd.filter(s => s.split(",")(6).length() == 1)

rdd1.saveAsTextFile("wasbs:///myOutputs")
}
}
```

C#:

```
public void runCurrentJob()
    {
        List<string> args = new List<string> {}; // No parameters

        // JarFile leads to "wasbs:///tmp/default_artifact.jar"
        // JarClass is the name of my main class -> "HDInsightScala"
        var parameters = new MapReduceJobSubmissionParameters
        {
            JarFile = "wasbs:///"+ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["jarPath"],
            JarClass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mainClassName"],
            //Arguments = args
        };

        var jobResponse = hdiJobManager.JobManagement.SubmitMapReduceJob(parameters);
        var jobID = jobResponse.JobSubmissionJsonResponse.Id;
        MessageBox.Show("My job ID is " + jobID + "\n wait for  completion . . .");
        var jobDetail = hdiJobManager.JobManagement.GetJob(jobID).JobDetail;
        while (!jobDetail.Status.JobComplete)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            jobDetail = hdiJobManager.JobManagement.GetJob(jobID).JobDetail;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("JOB IS COMPLETE.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, based on my understanding, you were able to submit your scala code as a spark job to HDInsight Spark Cluster via `Intellij Azure Plugin` and works.

According to the offical document [Use HDInsight Tools in Azure Toolkit for IntelliJ to create Spark applications for HDInsight Spark Linux cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-apache-spark-intellij-tool-plugin)， it seems that the IntelliJ plugin will help packaging your scala code and uploading these job files to cluster, then submit the job to yarn manager to run.

So to troubleshooting your issue, I think the first step is check whether you had packaged your scala code to a job and upload them to HDFS. Secondly, you can refer to the REST API `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/hdinsightspark/hdinsight-spark-batch-job#create-a-new-batch-job` to try to submit the job to run via some HTTP client like `postman`.

Then, you can follow the steps above for troubleshooting to debug & improve you C# code to make it works. Hope it helps.

Comment: I've managed to post it to livy/batches using RESTsharp, thanks!